# Can't find Unicode property definition "o" - Regular expression is not working in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to capture a sub-string from a string for that i am using regx but its is not working. The error which i am getting is `Can't find Unicode property definition "o"`

I am using Windows machine for running the below code.

Here is the code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $path = 'C:\APTscripts\APStress\Logs\APStress_September-18---20.44.25\APTLogs\PostBootLogs\09-18-2014_15-18-32\UILogs_09-18-2014_15-50-43.txt';
my ($captured) = $path =~ /(.+?) \PostBootLogs/gx;
print "$captured\n";
```

Comment: The `/g` is wastefully useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to escape the backslash in the pattern:

```
/(.+?) \\PostBootLogs/gx
```

You were inadvertently triggering the use of [Unicode character properties](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D) with the use of `\P`.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been demonstrated, you need to escape your literal backslashes in regular expressions.

```
my ($captured) = $path =~ /(.+?) \\PostBootLogs/x;
```

However, you can also accomplish this same task without a regex though if you use [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) or a similar file and directory managing module.

```
use Path::Class;

my $captured = file($path)->dir->parent->parent;
```